# iPad Navigation Based Application

Tags: ipad

I want to Build an iPad application which will fetch data from MS SQL database, i want to show those datas in Parent child manner (Tree View). How can i show those data in parent child manner using navigation based manner, is it possible to load information automattically in Navigation bars..?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

if your asking if it's possible to load navigation data into a sqlite database then the answer is yes but it might require a bit of processing